# Under which circumstances is jsessionid not sent?

Tags: jsp, jsessionid

I just fixed a bug in a webapplication which caused some data sent to the server to be ignored. I suspected it had to do with sessions which were being mismatched so I logged some requests and soon enough I had my answer: certain requests did not send the cookie with jsessionid, furthermore I noticed this only happened when identical requests were sent.

So I added a useless count attribute to the serialisation of my form, and now the cookie is sent each time.

Does anybody have information on the reason of this behavior or specifications of this mechanism?

The requests were made using jQuery's Ajax function.